# Java 7 Default GC for server

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jit

(a) In the GC logs, I can see the below lines printed even when the
application is idle. Is this something to do with JIT or some other JVM
internal operation?

```
2015-03-05T14:42:18.320+0000: 520807.126: Total time for which application
threads were stopped: 0.0000500 seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:18.320+0000: 520807.126: Application time: 0.0000240
seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:18.320+0000: 520807.126: Total time for which application
threads were stopped: 0.0000500 seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:58.405+0000: 520847.212: Application time: 40.0857170
seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:58.406+0000: 520847.212: Total time for which application
threads were stopped: 0.0001980 seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:58.406+0000: 520847.212: Application time: 0.0000250
seconds
2015-03-05T14:42:58.406+0000: 520847.212: Total time for which application
threads were stopped: 0.0000520 seconds
2015-03-05T14:43:28.406+0000: 520877.213: Application time: 30.0001550
second
```

(b)Using default GC collector. We are trying to print the tenuring distribution in the logs, but it won't print.

We have tried +PrintTenuringDistribution and also -PrintTenuringDistribution, but neither work. Is this not configured to work with Default Parallel GC?

Server Information

```
OS: RHEL 6
Cores: 24
RAM: 37GB
Java: Oracle JDK 7 Update 45
```

Answer (score 0):

> (a) In the GC logs, I can see the below lines printed even when the application is idle. Is this something to do with JIT or some other JVM internal operation?

Unlikely.

Under normal circumstances, ff the application is (really) idle, there won't be any JIT compilation or any other JVM internal activity.  That means that the GC won't be run.

I suspect that the activity is caused by a javaagent that you are using; e.g. to monitor the JVM.  (A javaagent will generate garbage under normal operation ...)

---

> Is this not configured to work with Default Parallel GC?

I've seen evidence (Google search results) that imply that it does work for the Default Parallel GC in Java 7.  I would check that you are specifying the option correctly; i.e.

```
  -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will retry on the print tenuring distribution. When I meant idle, I was referring to usual processing. If there was a garbage collection, shouldn't I see before and after GC heap/young etc information like I see during activity? Will also check if a javaagent was configured for that period.

Comment: Those log messages could actually be caused by javaagent activity.  An agent may have to freeze all threads to do certain things ... and that might be logged.